# Query sometimes take 25 seconds to run

Tags: sql-server, query-performance

After a set of usual data access queries run, SQL Server 2019 gets into a state where one specific query takes almost exactly 25 seconds to execute. Under normal conditions it takes 200 ms.

When I change the query in some seemingly unrelated ways (remove ORDER BY, some columns from SELECT list or AND condition) it runs normally, when I restore it to initial form, it takes 25 seconds again.

SQL Server maintains this state for around 10 executions of the query. Then it continues to run normally. No blocking or dead lock traces in SQL Profiler.

Why this might happen and how to track the issue?

PS: Thanks for all the replies, I will provide more data

- The query runs on development machine, there is not much else, no load or data variation
- Query is run with exactly the same parameters and returns the same set of data (3 rows), but it usually takes 200 ms while sometimes starts taking almost exactly 25 seconds. Looks like SQL Server waits for some locked resource, timeouts but then returns correct data anyway, no error info is shown.
- Query is quite simple, just a set of joins

Comment: More info could be useful. Query plans, the query itself...

Comment: Regarding the fixing itself do you have the "last good plan" auto tuning option enabled?

Comment: It is a simple query which always returns 3 rows and takes 200 ms, but the same query with the same parameters and returned data set sometimes starts taking almost exactly 25 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I issued `exec sp_updatestats` and no more 25 seconds query executions. Same data, same queries. I believe however it will start degrading again after a while. Which worries me as if db engine comes to a screeching halt on dev database with a hundred records how soon it will become unusable on prod system? Maybe we'll have to update stats every hour or so?

PS: In the end the problem was in too little RAM on dev laptop. Seems like the problem happened when it was full and started interacting with hard drive. This probably caused some kind of locks, because even so execution time was too large. After doubling the RAM the problem went away for good.

Comment: Just had this exact problem with precisely 25 seconds wait on a previously fast query. `sp_updatestats` fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Compare the execution plans. Could be a parameter sniffing issue.

If the plans are the same, compare the IO for the queries - look for physical reads when it’s slow compared to logical reads when it’s quicker. This would be if there’s memory pressure.

Comment: It runs on local development machine, no stress at all. Always returns 3 rows of data. Query is quite simple. Why would SQL Server took almost exactly 25 seconds to run a simple query? Waiting for some resources and timeouting?

Comment: We can't answer that unless you give us anything to go on. that is why we ask for the execution plans. You can even look for wait stats in the actual plan nowadays. So, start with the actual plan!

Comment: Sorry I can't provide specific information on the query since it is proprietary information, but I was wondering if there are common patterns to solving such problems.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on the Query Store, then look at the reports.  See

[Monitoring performance by using the Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I did enable Query Store but my query is nowhere to be found. It just shows statistics for some system queries in "Top Resource Consuming Queries". I believe I should use "Tracked Queries" but where do I get query ID from?